# Splitting a wide table by columns into two tables but with same table number and name

Tags: tables, split

I have to create a table with several columns. I couldn't create it as a single table because number of columns will not fit into a single page. So I split the table by showing some columns first and the rest later.

[image]

Here you can see the same table named differently, according to the split (table 3 and 4). Is there a way to give the same table name for the each split (only as table 3)?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[p]
  \caption{Summary results}
  
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{lllllllllllcp{2.5in}} \hline
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{t 1}} &
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{t 2}}    \\ 
    & \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{a} &
   \textbf{a}& \textbf{b} &
   \textbf{b}& \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{a} &
  \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} &
   \textbf{b} \\\hline
   \textbf{Predictor} &  & \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0}& \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0} \\\hline
  A scale & 0.14 &  0.16 &  0.14 &  & & 0.14 &  0.16 &  0.14  \\
    
 D  scale  &    0.22    & 0.28  &   0.27  & &  &    0.25 &  0.28 &  0.27\\
 



   \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[p]
  \caption{Summary results.}
  
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{lllllllllllcp{2.5in}} \hline
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{t 3}} &
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{t 4}}    \\ 
    & \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{a} &
   \textbf{a}& \textbf{b} &
   \textbf{b}& \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{a} &
  \textbf{a} & \textbf{b} &
   \textbf{b} \\\hline
   \textbf{Predictor} &  & \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0}& \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0} \\\hline
  A scale & 0.14 &  0.16 &  0.14 &  & & 0.14 &  0.16 &  0.14  \\
    
 D  scale  &    0.22    & 0.28  &   0.27  & &  &    0.25 &  0.28 &  0.27\\
 



   \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Just use a single table environment containing two tabulars.

Comment: Off-topic: Do use `\centering` directives, not `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` in `figure` and `table` floats.

Comment: @Bernard - I think (though I may be wrong...) that the OP's issue is that the two `tabular` envrionments are too large to fit on a single page. Hence, encasing them both in a single `table` directive may not be the way to go.

Comment: Incidentally, have you considered using a single `longtable` environment instead of two `tabular`/`table` combinations?

Comment: @Mico: I thought of this solutions, but as the O.P. seemed, as I understood it, to want have two tabulars separated  by some vertical space, the solution of two vertically aligned tabulars was more natural, from my point of view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may achieve your formatting objective by loading the `caption` package and issuing a `\ContinuedFloat` directive after starting the second `table` environment (and before issuing the associated `\caption` directive, of course). As the following example demonstrates, the arguments of the `\caption` directives needn't be identical.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption} % for \ContinuedFloat macro
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip} % optional

\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{2} % just for this example

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
  \caption{Summary results}
  \begin{tabular}{lllllllllllc p{2.5in}} 
  \hline
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{t 1}} 
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{t 2}} \\ 
    & \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{a} &
   \textbf{a}& \textbf{b} &
   \textbf{b}& \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{a} &
   \textbf{a}& \textbf{b} &
   \textbf{b} \\
   \hline
   \textbf{Predictor} &  & \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0}& \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0}& \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0}& \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0} \\
   \hline
   A scale & 0.14 & 0.16 & 0.14 & & & 0.14 & 0.16 & 0.14 \\    
   D scale & 0.22 & 0.28 & 0.27 & & & 0.25 & 0.28 & 0.27 \\
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
  \caption{Summary results, continued}
  \begin{tabular}{lllllllllllc p{2.5in}} 
  \hline
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{t 3}} 
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{t 4}}    \\ 
    & \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{a} &
   \textbf{a}& \textbf{b} &
   \textbf{b}& \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{a} &
   \textbf{a}& \textbf{b} &
   \textbf{b} \\
   \hline
   \textbf{Predictor} &  & \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0}& \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0}& \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0}& \textbf{1} &
   \textbf{0} \\
   \hline
   A scale & 0.14 & 0.16 & 0.14 & & & 0.14 & 0.16 & 0.14 \\
   D scale & 0.22 & 0.28 & 0.27 & & & 0.25 & 0.28 & 0.27 \\
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for the answer. I have a quick question. Will this method separate two tables in to two pages, if there are if there are several rows ?(so that both tables will not fit into a single page)

Comment: @student_R123 - Indeed, if the contents of the `table` environments are too large to fit on the same page, they'll be placed on separate pages. Incidentally, this is true of *all* `table` environments, not just those that contain `\ContinuedFloat` directives.